# RX-Android + ViewModel + Retrofit doesn't call OnComplete()

Tags: mvvm, rx-java, retrofit2, reactive-programming, rx-android

I cannot get the OnComplete() method to be called after all items are processed. I need to do so in order to (al the very least) hide the loading view. I'm a little new to JavaRX so I don't know where exactly is the problem. Can you help me to get the OnComplete() called when all items are processed?

The code does the following:

1. Show the loading view and get the list of items (just references).
2. Check if they are local or remote items.
3. If they are local, get them and add them to the list.
4. If they are remote, download them and add them to the list.
5. With the list built, draw the data on the UI.
6. Final processing and hiding of the loading view.

The code is the following:

```
private void loadDataRX(final long fromTime, final long toTime) {
    mLoadingPb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    iCompositeDisposable.clear();
    iCompositeDisposable.add(mViewModel.getItems(fromTime, toTime)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(items -> {
                Activity context = ItemFragment.this.getActivity();
                if (context == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Cannot present results: context is null");
                    return Flowable.empty();
                } else {
                    context.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        mItems.clear();
                        mCustomView.reset();
                    });
                    if (items != null && items.size() > 0) {
                        return Flowable.just(items);
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "No items.");
                        return Flowable.just(Collections.singletonList(new Item(-1))); // This is my current way of solving a similar problem so as to know if I don't have any items
                    }
                }
            })
            .concatMapIterable(items -> items)
            .concatMap(item -> {
                if (item.getUid() == -1) {
                    return Flowable.just(item);
                }
                String file = item.getFileName();
                boolean uploaded = item.isUploaded();
                if (uploaded) { // Remote file
                    if (item.getUid() > 0) {
                        return iRetrofit.create(RestApi.class).getItem(item.getUid());
                    } else {
                        return Flowable.empty();
                    }
                } else { // Local file
                    return Flowable.just(item);
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(item -> {
                Log.i(TAG, "Loaded items RX");
                if (item instanceof Item) {
                    //Do stuff with the item and the files
                } else if (item instanceof ResponseBody) {
                    //This is dirty but I didn't find another way. So here I basically extract the items and the files from the server's response. At least, it works.
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "No results for the given dates");
                }
            }, throwable -> {
                mLoadingPb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
            }, () -> {
                mLoadingPb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.i(TAG, "Loading results completed"); // Can't get this to be called
            })
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `mViewModel.getItems` returns `Flowable`. For flowable to complete we need to explicitly dispose it.

To resolve that you can make `mViewModel.getItems` to return `Single<List<ItemType>>`, then transform stream using `.flatMapObservable { Observable.fromIterable(it) }` to process each item.

Comment: Hmmm could you elaborate a little bit more? It is true it returns a `Flowable` but, as per the documentation, `Single` won't fire the onComplete either...

Comment: Yes, `Single` will fire `onSuccess` that can be used instead of `onComplete`. `Flowable` is good for subscribing to stream and listen, for example, to changes in database. If you need just to retrive some data in background thread once than `Single` will fit your needs.